# How to detach ICommand from element after it was executed?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

After the command was executed I'd like to detach it from `StackPanel`'s `PreviewMouseDown` event so it won't be called again.

Is it possible to do?

```
<StackPanel>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown" >
          <GalaSoftMvvmLight:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
                            PassEventArgsToCommand="False" />
       </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be oversimplifying this, but have you just tried setting MyCommand equal to null in your view model after it is called once.

Comment: I tried it but didn't help. It seems that wpf makes its own copy of command.

Comment: You might try setting your binding to explicitly two-way. Command="{Binding MyCommand, Mode=TwoWay}". It has been a while and I am not sure if the mode is one-way by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify a `CanExecute` condition in your view model, then set it to `False` after the method runs once.

Here's a quick view model I threw together to test it, using Prism's `DelegateCommand`.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public DelegateCommand MyCommand { get; set; }
    private bool canExecute = true;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(SayHi, () => canExecute);
    }

    public void SayHi()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hi");

        canExecute = false;
    }
}
```